# Getting all the parameters except for the first one [Lua]

Tags: loops, parameters, lua

So, I was trying to get only the second, third, etc.. parameters of a table, but I couldn't manage to do it.

Here's my code:

```
tArgs = {...}

local command = tArgs[1]
table.remove(tArgs, 1)

local paramNum = 0
local params = ""
local iteration = 1

for _, file in ipairs(tArgs) do
    paramNum = paramNum + 1
    while iteration < paramNum do
        parms = params .. tArgs[iteration]
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simpler solution:

```
params = table.concat(tArgs,"",2)
```

Answer (score 2):

It'd be easier to just not save the first param into the table:

```lua
local command = ...
local tArgs = {select(2, ...)}
```

Answer (score 0):

```lua
local iteration = 2

while iteration < #tArgs do
    parms = params .. tArgs[iteration]
    iteration = iteration + 1    
end
```

don't forget to set the `iteration` variable to `2`, since the first value of a table starts with index 1

Comment: `for iteration=2,#tArgs do parms = params .. tArgs[iteration] end` is simpler